# Hard coded string causes an error in the manifest of android

Tags: android, android-xml

I programmed hardcoded manifest file, like below:
`<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="111111111111" />`
In this case, facebook sdk couldn't detect meta-data definition.
But, the way to reference string value works well.
I aware the reason of using string resource file is for performance issue. however, there seems to be another reason.
What's that?

Comment: You would have to ask Facebook that question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mr. Murphy, I tried the same but at the end i had to put the Facebook App Id inside my Strings.xml, probably security reasons, your FB App Id must be "loaded from your project".

the example described in the documentation does the same:

> To update your app, first add a reference to your App ID into the
>   AndroidManifest.xml file. Since you are no longer using your App ID to
>   instantiate a Facebook object, you will need to include the following
>   line to allow the SDK to identify your application on Facebook:

```
   <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

> Next, add a string resource to your strings.xml file with your App ID.

```
 <string name="app_id">12345678910</string>
```